# Why am I getting this InvalidOperationException in this C# wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, progress-bar

I have a C# (WPF) program that searches through files in a directory, and I wanted a progress bar to show my progress searching through the files in the directory (since there could be thousands of files in a directory).

I decided to use background workers so that the progress bar updates correctly (which isn't happening, but that's not my biggest problem).

Currently what happens is it SOMETIMES works which is super weird, but most times I get this error.  The only time I don't get this error is if I add a `MessageBox.Show();` in the `foreach(document in myDirectory)` loop to slow it down and view what number file it's on.  Then it only errors out every so often.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it?  Also, if you think there's a better method to show the progress bar, please don't hesitate to correct what I'm doing.

**My error**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.

**myApp.xaml.cs**

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;

public void searchFiles()
{
    //50 files in the directory
    int fileCount = 50;
    int documentCounter = 0;
    //For every file in the directory
    foreach(document in myDirectory)
    {
    //increment the file count
    documentCounter++;
    FileSearchProgressBar(documentCounter, fileCount);
    }
}

private void FileSearchProgressBar(int currentDocNumber, int count)
{
    backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (obj, ea) => CalculateProgress(currentDocNumber, count);
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(progressReport);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void progressReport(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void CalculateProgress(int currentDocNumber, int count)
{
    //This is where the error is reporting
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(currentDocNumber * (100 / count));
}
```

**EDIT1**

**Stack Trace**

`System.InvalidOperationException: This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.
  at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.VerifyNotCompleted()
  at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object arg)
  at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Int32 percentProgress, Object userState)
  at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Int32 percentProgress)
  at HR_Search_Program.MainWindow.CalculateProgress(Int32 currentDocNumber, Int32 count) in c:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myproject\myproject\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 589`

Comment: Where does `backgroundWorker1` come from? You're trying to create one for each `document`, but without the declaration we can't tell the scope.

Comment: looks to me cross thread exception try putting a try catch and see the stacktrace and post here please

Comment: @HABO thanks for pointing that out.  I added the declaration.

Comment: @sumeetkumar I'll post that under EDIT1 soon, thanks

Comment: How many progress bars are being updated by all of the background workers? Assuming one, how are the results summarized so that they all contribute to one progress bar? Why have you chosen to declare `backgroundWorker1` outside `FileSearchProgressBar()`, but you keep overwriting it for each document?

Comment: So, I'm new to wpf, and C#, so it's very possible that I'm doing this incorrectly (obviously I am b/c there's errors).  What's happening now is that the progress bar updates a % per file it searches, when it gets done searching through the files it hits 100%, and it starts on the next search.  I'm running the search multiple times since I'm searching for multiple words in files.  So I get a single search bar for each word I'm searching for in the file, but only one bar shows at a time.  I may need to add some more code.

Comment: @sumeetkumar added the stack trace.  Looks like thread problem (as assumed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted can't even compile. It's not syntactically correct. Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is, never mind what the best solution is. But there are some clues in your post:

- The exception is clearly stating that your code is attempting to call the `ReportProgress()` method on a `BackgroundWorker` object that represents an operation that has already been completed.
- The code that starts the `BackgroundWorker` creates a new instance for each document in your `myDirectory` collection, and assigns the reference of this new instance to a single variable, `backgroundWorker1`.

Since you have multiple instances of `BackgroundWorker` running concurrently, but can only keep track of a single instance at a time, it is most likely that an instance started later is completing first, and an instance started earlier is trying to report progress, but can only use the reference of the instance that started later to do so. Since that later-started instance has already completed, the exception is thrown.

One fix would be to simply have the `CalculateProgress()` method take as a parameter the `BackgroundWorker` reference that is sent to the `DoWork` event handler. That way, each instance of the `BackgroundWorker` would use *itself* to report progress instead of trying to use the most-recently-started one.

But it seems unlikely that it's actually a good idea for you to use more than one `BackgroundWorker` instance in the first place. A better implementation is a single instance of `BackgroundWorker`, where the loop that enumerates the documents is in that worker's `DoWork` event handler.

It's my hope that the above is enough information for you to recognize the error in your code and fix it. If not, please provide a good code example, so that it can be modified so as to illustrate what I mean above.